# Without using logarithm rules, how to calculate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} R(n)^n$ for a rational function $R$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Well, without using logarithm rules, how to calculate this limit? $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n^2+8n\:-1}{n^2-4n-5}\right)^n$$

I can't find any more "nice" presentation of this fraction, and i can't use $\ln $ rules..

Comment: The denominator factors as $(n-5)(n+1)$

Comment: Factor both denominator and numerator into linear terms and use the formula $(1+1/n)^n\to e$?

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to avoid that since the result is $e^{12}$...

Comment: Hint: the fraction is approximately $(1+8/n)/(1-4/n))\approx1+12/n$.

Comment: $$\left(\frac{n^2+8n\:-1}{n^2-4n-5}\right)^n = \frac{\left(1+\frac{4+\sqrt{17}}{n}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{4-\sqrt{17}}{n}\right)^n}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\left(1-\frac{5}{n}\right)^n}$$

Now, use the fact that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^n = e^a$$

Comment: @r9m, very clear. That should be an answer, even the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{n^2+8n-1}{n^2-4n-5}=1+\frac{n^2+8n-1}{n^2-4n-5}-1=1+\frac{12n+4}{n^2-4n-5}$$

$$\left(\frac{n^2+8n-1}{n^2-4n-5}\right)^n=\left[\left(1+\frac{12n+4}{n^2-4n-5}\right)^\dfrac{n^2-4n-5}{12n+4}\right]^{\dfrac{n(12n+4)}{n^2-4n-5}}$$

For $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{12n+4}{n^2-4n-5}\right)^\dfrac{n^2-4n-5}{12n+4}=e$

For the exponent,
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n(12n+4)}{n^2-4n-5}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{12+4/n}{1-4/n-5/n^2}=12$